# cobbler managed dnsmasq is not listening on the correct interfaces

Tags: centos, dhcp, port, dnsmasq, cobbler

I have a cobbler server I am trying to get installed.  Unfortunately dnsmasq is not listening on the correct interfaces.

It should be listening on my 192.168.10.2 network which is assigned to br1

```
[root@cob log]# ip address show | awk '/\<inet\>/ { print $NF, '\t', $2 }'
lo  127.0.0.1/8
br0  172.16.10.2/24
br1  192.168.10.2/24
virbr0  192.168.122.1/24
```

However it is not doing so.

```
[root@cob log]# netstat -planu | egrep -v "::|Local|\(serv" | awk -F' ' '{ print $4"\t","|------|", $7 }'
0.0.0.0:53       |------| 6526/dnsmasq
127.0.0.1:960    |------| 3752/rpc.statd
0.0.0.0:67       |------| 6526/dnsmasq
0.0.0.0:37444    |------| 3752/rpc.statd
0.0.0.0:69       |------| 3922/xinetd
0.0.0.0:111      |------| 3445/rpcbind
0.0.0.0:631      |------| 3781/cupsd
0.0.0.0:652      |------| 3445/rpcbind
```

The server is not serving DHCP on the correct network.

```
[root@cob log]# nmap -sU -v 192.168.10.2
...
PORT      STATE         SERVICE
53/udp    open|filtered domain
67/udp    open|filtered dhcps
69/udp    open|filtered tftp
111/udp   open          rpcbind
631/udp   open|filtered ipp
37444/udp open|filtered unknown
```

nmap shows that it is being served on the correct interface via UD but that it is being filtered. However I have made rules in iptables for them to prevent this.

```
[root@cob log]# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5910 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 25150 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25151 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25150 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 25151 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25152 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 25152 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

My dnsmasq config file...

```
# Cobbler generated configuration file for dnsmasq
# Fri Mar  6 13:22:03 2015

# resolve.conf .. ?
#no-poll
#enable-dbus
read-ethers
addn-hosts = /var/lib/cobbler/cobbler_hosts
interface=br1
dhcp-range=br1,192.168.10.220,192.168.10.240
dhcp-option=3,192.168.10.2
dhcp-lease-max=1000
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0
dhcp-boot=net:normalarch,pxelinux.0
dhcp-boot=net:ia64,/var/lib/cobbler/elilo-3.6-ia64.efi
```

I've looked all over trying various solutions but, I cannot get dnsmasq to work on the correct port number. If possible I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

DNSMasq is listening on all interfaces. I don't know why it is ignoring your cobbler config. Check your logs for information. I know for example eth0:N interfaces are not valid, perhaps brN interfaces are the same.

- Check that the dnsmasq conf file reflects the cobbler config.
- Try using listen-address instead of interface. Note what the man page says about loopback.